# How to indent a xml manually with a xslt?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, signature

I have a xml containing a signature (xmldsig). Now I want to indent my xml (except the signature which would become invalid). How would this be possible through a xslt? The `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>` is not an option because it indents my signature as well. I'm using the Jaxb marshaller to serialize my java object with a transformer which gets a xslt file as source. Any ideas how this could be solved?

Thanks!

Edit:

With XSLT3 and the `suppress-indentation="ns2:Signature"` flag the signure itself isn't indented anymore. But the xml is still invalid because the signature tag is indented which introduces new characters -> invalid signature

[image]

What do I have to do in my xsd to get the signature element in the same row as birth (this should be generic e.g. the last element before the signature)

Comment: In XSLT 3, there is a `suppress-indentation` attribute on `xsl:output`: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#serialization. That might help to not change the element for the signature.

Comment: Can you place your signature in a `<![CDATA[` section?  That might prevent its being altered by `indent="yes"`.

Comment: Which XML elements are you allowed to indent at all if there is a signature? Does the signature only apply to part of the XML? It is not clear to me where the signature allows any indentation at all.

Comment: I have a user object which is serialized to a xml string (pretty print). This string will be signed and can be validated correctly. The problem is now that the signature gets invalid if you deserialize the signed xml string and reserialize it with the jaxb marshaller and unmarshaller. This flow object -> string -> signedstring -> object -> signedstring works perfectly if the "pretty print or formatting" feature is disabled (at the beginning of this flow). I just want to check if it is possible to make this thing work with the formatting feature turned on.